# Caret issue in Safari with contenteditable SVG

Tags: html, svg, safari

I am using `contenteditable="true"` to edit text in SVG. In all browsers except Safari it works.
Safari has an issue with caret position:
[image: SVG caret issue]

Sample code:

```css
[contenteditable]{
  -webkit-user-select:text;
  user-select:text;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true"  style="background: #ffe7e7">
  <svg style="display:inline-block">
    <text id="text" y="2em">Hello world</text>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Webkit has a ton (353) of open bugs for contenteditable - so this is not surprising.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have solved the issue by implementing our own caret. System caret is hidden by style rule.

Comment: this would be a good answer if you explained how you did that.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar issue in the past.  Unfortunately, the answer was to admit that safari sometimes has particular issues and I had to decide between supporting safari for that or rethinking the approach.  Since I didn't want to drop saffari, I totally rethought the need for that layout, but YMMV.  You can find the issue tracker for safari issues related to `contenteditable` [here](https://bugs.webkit.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=contenteditable).

Answer (score -1):

If your Safari browser is up to date ([contenteditable is fully supported from 3.1.](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_contenteditable.asp)), most likely your problem is that webkit and safari are *very* buggy with contenteditable. Here are [Safari's bugs](https://bugs.webkit.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=contenteditable).

Comment: If lower than 3.1, contenteditable isn't supported.

Comment: the version, I mean